# jquery validate - Possible to change submitted field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a custom method

```
$.validator.addMethod("lettersandspaces", function(value, element) {
    var value = this.elementValue(element).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, 'Your name may only contain letters');
```

Here I am trimming whitespace and replacing any repeating whitespaces with only one. I am then validating to make sure there are only letters and spaces.

Is it possible to make it so the trimmed `value` is submitted with the form instead of what the user entered?

Comment: Yes, use jQuery to manipulate the form's data before submitting it.  However, that has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [submitHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) and you can make any action before submiting the form ,(form.submit())

See beleow a working snippet

```js
$.validator.addMethod("lettersandspaces", function(value, element) {
    var value = this.elementValue(element).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, 'Your name may only contain letters');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                lettersandspaces: true
            },
            "age": {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            },
            "age": {
                required: "Please, enter your age",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            var newName  = $("#name").val().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
            $("#name").val(newName);
            $(form).valid();
            alert("Name = '"+newName+"'");
            
            // comment return and uncomment form.submit(
            return false;  //form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br><br>
    <label for="age">Age :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="age" name="age" id="age" /><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In validation form by jquery. If you want change value input name before validate. Let try:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        'name': {
            normalizer: function(){
                return $('#name').val().(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
            }
        }
    }    
})
```

Comment: According to the docs - https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/- the value submitted with the form isn't transformed, it only changes it for validation.